# How to stop Parity node cleanly?

Tags: parity

To connect to the ethereum test network and sync the blockchain, I run:

```
parity --chain testnet
```

When I have to stop at some point, I do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and it says:

> Finishing work, please wait... and quits

However when I check for processes running, I still see the process running:

```
/usr/local/bin/parity sync
```

I am doing `kill -9 <pid>` to kill the process. There has to be a better way. I couldn't find anything in the docs. What is a clean way to stop the node?

Answer (score 3):

The answer is: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>+<kbd>Patience</kbd>.

> However when I check for processes running, I still see the process running.

I can reproduce this behaviour. The problem is the client processing a network [DoS](https://blog.ethereum.org/2016/09/22/ethereum-network-currently-undergoing-dos-attack/) [attack](https://blog.ethereum.org/2016/09/18/security-alert-geth-nodes-crash-due-memory-bug/). It had been spammed for [several](https://blog.ethereum.org/2016/09/22/transaction-spam-attack-next-steps/) weeks. You need to wait for a couple of minutes. Sometimes 10-15.

Yesterday (Oct-19, 2016) was a [hard fork](https://blog.ethereum.org/2016/10/18/faq-upcoming-ethereum-hard-fork/) to mitigate that attack by [increasing gas costs](https://blog.ethereum.org/2016/10/13/announcement-imminent-hard-fork-eip150-gas-cost-changes/) for several operations. After block [2,463,000](https://fork.codetract.io/) your synchronization process will go back to normal and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> will work without the magic <kbd>Patience</kbd> component.

Comment: I am having this issue on testnet. DoS attack on the main network wouldn't have any impact on the test network correct?

Comment: @5chdn how about for parity 1.9 on windows where its started not in a command window ?

Answer (score 1):

I just checked on my own parity node, and I'm getting a different result :

**--- PARITY running**

```
$ parity --testnet --jsonrpc-apis "eth,net,web3" --jsonrpc-cors '*' --jsonrpc-interface 0.0.0.0 --jsonrpc-port 8545 --jsonrpc-hosts="all"  --no-dapps

$ ps aux | grep parity
gregoir+ 23211 11.1  2.2 410128 168884 pts/0   Sl+  13:46   0:04 parity --testnet --jsonrpc-apis eth,net,web3 --jsonrpc-cors * --jsonrpc-interface 0.0.0.0 --jsonrpc-port 8545 --jsonrpc-hosts=all --no-dapps
gregoir+ 23225 13.5  0.6 184576 50820 pts/0    Sl+  13:47   0:05 /home/gregoire_jeanmart/.cargo/bin/parity sync
gregoir+ 23310  0.0  0.0  12944  1084 pts/2    S+   13:47   0:00 grep --color=auto parity
```

**--- PARITY stopped (via Ctrl+C)**

> 16-10-15 13:48:07 UTC Finishing work, please wait...

```
$ ps aux | grep parity
gregoir+ 23400  0.0  0.0  12944  1092 pts/2    S+   13:48   0:00 grep --color=auto parity
```

Well are you sure you don't have a daemon running ?

Comment: I don't have a daemon running. I just tried: started the node and killed it within few seconds and it shut down cleanly. I then started again, let it find some peer nodes and start syncing and then killed and I see the process still running in the background.

Comment: You are only running `parity --chain testnet` (no more option after ?) .Otherwise, which version do you use (`parity --version`) ?

Comment: I have tried running with just --chain testnet and also the one you have above. Version is: Parity/v1.4.0-unstable-d6cad29-20161008/x86_64-macos/rustc1.12.0. I should have also mentioned, it is on mac os 10.11.4.

Comment: I tried to add more log by adding this option `--logging debug` but when I stopped Parity, I only got one more line ```2016-10-15 17:05:34 UTC main DEBUG hyper::server  closing server 0.0.0.0:8545```. You can check if you have the result

Comment: Unfortunately I am seeing the exact same output after stopping, nothing else.